# Superconvergence of an approximate linear interpolation to the first derivative at the midpoint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Let's say we have an unknown real analytic function in one variable, $u(x)$. Let's also say we are able to approximate this function, say with the use of finite element methods or finite difference schemes assuming $u$ is the solution to some PDE over the interval $[0,1]$. Finally let, $u_n(x)$ represent the piecewise linear function approximately interpolating the function at some nodal points $0=x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_{n}=1.$ Note that this means $n\geq 1$. Define $h=x_{i+1}-x_i =\frac{1}{n}$.

In many instances, we have error bounds like:

$$\frac{u_n(x_{i})-u_n(x_{i-1})}{h} - u'(x_i) = O(h) \text{ for } i=1,...,n$$
and
$$\frac{u_n(x_{i})-u_n(x_{i-1})}{h} - u'(x_{i-1}) = O(h) \text{ for } i=1,...,n.$$

Assuming our approximation is good enough that the above two bounds hold, it seems like we ought to be able to prove:

$$\frac{u_n(x_{i})-u_n(x_{i-1})}{h} - u'\left(x_{i-1}+\frac{1}{2}h\right) = O(h^2) \text{ for } i=1,...,n$$

However, I've tried extensively using they usual Taylor's theorem approaches, I end up empty. Can anyone provide a counter example or a hint toward a proof? It's highly likely that if it's true I have been playing with the right pieces, but missing a crucial step. And if it's false, well, it'd just be nice to know I can stop trying. But additionally, what additional assumptions on $u$ or the approximates, $u_n$ would be required to estabilish the result.

Comment: What do you have at the nodes? If $u_n(x_i) = u(x_i) + O(h^3)$, then your problems vanish. If $u_n(x_i) = u(x_i) + O(h^2)$, then the first two equations are true, but we have problems with the third one.

Comment: I guess in the particular application I'm thinking of, we probably only have a second order approximation at the nodes. Still, it is surprising to me that we can't prove the third inequality in some special cases if not in full generality. To possibly abuse the heck out of notation, it's possible that $u_n(x_i) = u(x_{i}) +O(h^2)$ and $u_n(x_{i+1}) = u(x_{i+1}) -O(h^2)$ such that their difference cancels favorably. For example, it seems we could show from the intermediate value theorem that the finite difference is exactly equal to $u'(x)$ somewhere in each subinterval.